# Error filtering template: Invalid template file in module

Tags: magento2, phtml

I have this issue and I don't know how to solve it.

My phtml file is under:

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/josefsteiner/template/home.phtml
```

and i tried to include this phtml file into my CMS site like this:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_block" template="rwd_josefsteiner::home.phtml"}}
```

But i get always this error:

> Error filtering template: Invalid template file: 'rwd_josefsteiner::home.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'magento\framework\view\element\template_0'

how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you done these two steps https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html and https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html

Comment: not all, i will do it right now

Comment: Composer file is optional, You can create it later

Comment: i got now a own theme, and i changed it in the admin panel, still got this error, do i need to change the path or something?

Comment: Check my answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/304506/59677

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Magento 2, your PHTML file should be under the

> app/design/frontend/rwd/josefsteiner/Magento_Theme/templates/home.phtml

Here **rwd** is your theme Vendor or namespace and **josefsteiner** is your theme name

And you have to call it on CMS like

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::home.phtml"}}
```